# ORACLE SQL: Find last minimum and maximum consecutive period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the sample data set below which list the water meters not working for specific reason for a certain range period (jan 2016 to december 2018).

[image: sample dataset]

I would like to have a query that retrieves the last maximum and minimum consecutive period where the meter was not working within that range of period.

[image: Expected result]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

```
select code, to_char(min_period, 'yyyymm') min_period, to_char(max_period, 'yyyymm') max_period
  from (
    select code, min(period) min_period, max(period) max_period,
           max(min(period)) over (partition by code) max_min_period
      from (
        select code, period, sum(flag) over (partition by code order by period) grp
          from (
            select code, period, 
                   case when add_months(period, -1) 
                             = lag(period) over (partition by code order by period) 
                        then 0 else 1 end flag
              from (select mrdg_acc_code code, to_date(mrdg_per_period, 'yyyymm') period from t)))
      group by code, grp)
  where min_period = max_min_period
```

Explanation:

- flag rows where period is not equal previous period plus one month,
- create column `grp` which sums flags consecutively,
- group data using `code` and `grp` additionaly finding maximal start of period,
- show only rows where `min_period` = `max_min_period`

Second option is recursive CTE available in Oracle 11g and above:

```
with 
  data(period, code) as (
    select to_date(mrdg_per_period, 'yyyymm'), mrdg_acc_code from t 
      where mrdg_per_period between 201601 and 201812),
  cte (period, code) as (
    select to_char(period, 'yyyymm'), code from data
      where (period, code) in (select max(period), code from data group by code)
    union all
    select to_char(data.period, 'yyyymm'), cte.code 
      from cte 
      join data on data.code = cte.code 
        and data.period = add_months(to_date(cte.period, 'yyyymm'), -1))
select code, min(period) min_period, max(period) max_period 
  from cte group by code
```

Explanation:

- subquery `data` filters only rows from `2016` - `2018` additionaly converting period to date format. We need this for function `add_months` to work.
- `cte` is recursive. Anchor finds starting rows, these with maximum period for each code. After `union all` is recursive member, which looks for the row one month *older* than current. If it finds it then net row, if not then stop.
- final select groups data. Notice that period which were not consecutive were rejected by `cte`.

Though recursive queries are slower than traditional ones, there can be scenarios where second solution is better.

Here is the [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a74c6bb1c4a7a985163b53a8a9cfa3b) for both queries. Good luck.

Comment: thank you Ponder Stibbons :) for the explanation. it works. i am new as dba and have many similar reports to work on. i have now understood the concept and follow same for other reports. thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

use aggregate function with group by

```
select max(mdrg_per_period) mdrg_per_period, mrdg_acc_code,max(mrdg_date_read),rea_Desc,min(mdrg_per_period) not_working_as_from
from tablename
group by mrdg_acc_code,rea_Desc
```

Comment: hi fa06, i did try same but could not get the desired result. for example for account 010100010 what i got every time for the minimum period is 201601 but it should be 201610 the last minimum period

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  This is a gap-and-islands problem.  To get all continuous periods, it will help if you have an enumeration of months.  So, convert the period to a number of months and then subtract a sequence generated using `row_number()`.  The difference is constant for a group of adjacent months.

This looks like:

```
select acc_code, min(period), max(period)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by acc_code order by period_num) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, floor(period / 100) * 12 + mod(period, 100) as period_num
            from t
           ) t
      where rea_desc = 'METER NOT WORKING'
     ) t
group by (period_num - seqnum);
```

Then, if you want the last one for each account, you can use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select acc_code, min(period), max(period),
             row_number() over (partition by acc_code order by max(period desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by acc_code order by period_num) as seqnum
            from (select t.*, floor(period / 100) * 12 + mod(period, 100) as period_num
                  from t
                 ) t
            where rea_desc = 'METER NOT WORKING'
           ) t
      group by (period_num - seqnum)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```